# iostream to zlib and files with C++?

Tags: c++, file, iostream, zlib

.NET has spoiled me and made me realize how simple certain things can be :(

With C++ i'd like to use either fopen or ostream/istream to push data to either zlib directly or to some kind of memory buffer (then zlib) then proceed to dump it to a file. I'd like something similar to load it back in.

I looked at zlibs example and while it looks simple it isnt an iostream or file and i need to use buffers. Does anyone know of a existing solution?

Comment: Please take a look at their examples again, especially in the `contrib/iostream3` directory. What's not to like about `gzifstream` and `gzofstream`?

Comment: @n-m: Works well. I'd accept the answer expect it isnt ;)

Comment: where are the gzifstream and gzofstream available?

Comment: Are you trying to just access a compressed GZip stream, or are you trying to write into a ZIP file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use boost IOstream API to read the zipped files and create an iostream. I wrote code for this based on Boost documentation. The code and a related question on how to read the zipped file line -by-line is available here:

[How can I read line-by-line using Boost IOStreams' interface for Gzip files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420620/read-line-by-line-using-boost-iostream-interface-for-gzip-files)

Comment: There are plenty of ways to get GZip without going through boost.