# How can I read line-by-line using Boost IOStreams' interface for Gzip files?

Tags: c++, boost, file-io, gzip, iostream

I managed to integrate the boost Iostream APIs for reading zipped files. I followed the documentation in boost page and have the following code so-far:

```
std::stringstream outStr;  
ifstream file("file.gz", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);  
try {  
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istreambuf in;  
    in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());  
    in.push(file);  
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, outStr);  
}  
catch(const boost::iostreams::gzip_error& exception) {  
    int error = exception.error();  
    if (error == boost::iostreams::gzip::zlib_error) {  
       //check for all error code    
    }   
}
```

The code works fine (so please ignore any typos. and errors above :)).

1. Looks like the above code will read the complete the file and store it in the memory while creating the filtering_istreambuf. Is that true, from my investigation it looks so to me? If the file is read into memory, this code can be an issue for large files (which is what I'm dealing with).
2. My current code reads the gzipped using gzgets API from zlib line by line. Is there a way to do line by line reading using boost APIs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1) Yes, the above code will `copy()` the entire file into the string buffer `outStr`. According to the [description of copy](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/functions/copy.html)

> The function template copy reads data from a given model of Source and writes it to a given model of Sink until the end of stream is reached.

2) switch from `filtering_istreambuf` to `filtering_istream` and std::getline() will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("file.gz", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    try {
        boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
        in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
        in.push(file);
        for(std::string str; std::getline(in, str); )
        {
            std::cout << "Processed line " << str << '\n';
        }
    }
    catch(const boost::iostreams::gzip_error& e) {
         std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

(you can `std::cout << file.tellg() << '\n';` inside that loop if you want proof. It will increase in sizeable chunks, but it won't be equal the length of the file from the start)

Comment: thanks. Let me try this out. I'm hoping to store <  in> as a class member. and have a member function in the class called getline. getline should be able to return line from current file pointer position.

Comment: I tried printing the stream position inside the loop and it is not working. `file.tellg()` returns a constant number if I use `std::ifstream` and 0 if I use `boost::iostream::file_source`. It returns -1 if I call it on the `in` stream. How can I get current position in file and be able to move to that position? Do I have to first dump all of the stream into another stream?