# How to get gzip_params from boost's gzip_decompressor()

Tags: c++, boost, gzip

I am using the boost gzip_decompressor() from the following link:
[How can I read line-by-line using Boost IOStreams' interface for Gzip files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420620/how-can-i-read-line-by-line-using-boost-iostreams-interface-for-gzip-files)

Reading the gzip file works fine, but how do I read the gzip_params?  I want to know the original file name that's stored in the gzip_params.file_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question.

The solution is to use `component<N, T>` to get a pointer to the actual decompressor instance:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/778c35c61cd14211)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("file.gz", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    try {
        boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
        using gz_t = boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor;
        in.push(gz_t());
        in.push(file);

        for(std::string str; std::getline(in, str); )
        {
            std::cout << "Processed line " << str << '\n';
        }

        if (gz_t* gz = in.component<0, gz_t>()) {
            std::cout << "Original filename: " << gz->file_name() << "\n";
            std::cout << "Original mtime: " << gz->mtime() << "\n";
            std::cout << "Zip comment: " << gz->comment() << "\n";
        }
    }
    catch(const boost::iostreams::gzip_error& e) {
         std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Preparing a sample file using

```
gzip testj.txt
mv testj.txt.gz file.gz
```

Prints

```
Processed line Hello world
Original filename: testj.txt
Original mtime: 1518987084
Zip comment:
```