# Trying to extract files in gzip to temporary folder in C++

Tags: c++, boost, gzip

I want to extract files in gzip using c++. I am using boost libraries. Here is my code:

```
//Read from the first command line argument, assume it's gzipped    
std::ifstream file(filepath, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> inbuf;
inbuf.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
inbuf.push(file);
boost::iostreams::copy(inbuf, cout);

//Cleanup
file.close();
```

This code is writing all the datas to terminal. However, I want to extract all the files seperately in to some folder.

Comment: Boost's gzip is meant to decompress raw data, not full zip archives. Are you trying to decompress a `.zip` file? Maybe just use `unzip` or `7z`? Also, your "cleanup" code is unnecessary.

Comment: It could be necessary, because we don't know the lifetimes of the objects involved.  What @BartekBanachewicz probably means is that you _can_ rely on RAII for the same

Comment: Do you understand that you copy the contents to the terminal when you use `boost::iostreams::copy(..., std::cout)` ? In C++, `std::cout` is the standard output , usually the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, just do as you say:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto dir = boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / "demo";
    boost::filesystem::create_directories(dir);

    for (boost::filesystem::path p : boost::make_iterator_range(argv+1, argv+argc)) {
        std::ifstream file(p.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
        boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> inbuf;
        inbuf.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
        inbuf.push(file);

        auto output = dir / p.filename();
        std::cout << "Writing " << output << "\n";
        std::ofstream ofs(output.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
        boost::iostreams::copy(inbuf, ofs);
    }
}
```

So, to run with one argument like  `./test test.cpp.gz` will write the unzipped outputs to files of the sasme name in the temporary directory:

```
$ ../build/sotest test.cpp.gz 
Writing "/tmp/demo/test.cpp.gz"
```

### How To Get The Original Filename?

I showed this in an other answer before: [How to get gzip_params from boost's gzip_decompressor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854998/how-to-get-gzip-params-from-boosts-gzip-decompressor/48856440#48856440)

So you'd get this:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
using gz_t = boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto dir = fs::temp_directory_path() / "demo";
    create_directories(dir);

    for (fs::path p : boost::make_iterator_range(argv+1, argv+argc)) {
        std::ifstream file(p.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
        boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> inbuf;
        inbuf.push(gz_t());
        inbuf.push(file);

        if (gz_t* gz = inbuf.component<0, gz_t>()) {
            auto output = dir / fs::unique_path(basename(p));
            {
                std::cout << "Writing " << output << "\n";
                std::ofstream ofs(output.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
                boost::iostreams::copy(inbuf, ofs);
            }

            std::cout << "Original filename: " << gz->file_name() << "\n";
            std::cout << "Original mtime: " << gz->mtime() << "\n";
            std::cout << "Zip comment: " << gz->comment() << "\n";
            if (!gz->file_name().empty()) {
                fs::rename(output, dir / fs::path(gz->file_name()).filename());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now if you run it like e.g.

```
$ gzip -k test.cpp
$ mv test.cpp. gz renamed.gz

$ ../build/sotest renamed.gz 
Writing "/tmp/demo/renamed"
Original filename: test.cpp
Original mtime: 1532692097
Zip comment: 

$ find /tmp/demo/
/tmp/demo/
/tmp/demo/test.cpp
```